# Adding a line at the mean of the data, ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, vline

I am trying to add a simple line to show the median and mean of my data in a ggplot2 bar chart.

Here is the code I have

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

data <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5)

count_data<- count(data)

mean <- mean(count_data)
med <- median(count_data)
ggplot(count_data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=freq), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean)) + 
  #facet_wrap(~Year, nrow=1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

I do see my data alright, but the vline does not show up. Would you know what's wrong?

Comment: Which package's `count` function are you using in line 2 - `plyr`?

Comment: Yup. Added that in the code @JonSpring

Comment: Did you mean `mean <- mean(data); med <- median(data)`? I get an error when I run those on `count_data`.

Comment: Damn, silly me, that was indeed the problem. Thanks for solving that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the mean/median frequency, given you have created `count_data`. To do this I have explicitly called the `freq` variable when creating `mean` and `med`. The below therefore has both lines on the barplot.

If you actually want the mean/median of `data`, then it should just be `mean(data)`, for example.

```
data <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5)

count_data<- plyr::count(data)

mean <- mean(count_data$freq)
med <- median(count_data$freq)
ggplot(count_data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x=x, y=freq), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = med)) +
  #facet_wrap(~Year, nrow=1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Great solution. You don't need to calculate the mean and median first, you can do this directly in the code to the same effect: *p + geom_vline(xintercept = mean(freq))*